# json response data not available in cross domain request

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, cross-domain, jsonp

Am making a cross domain request using jquery

```
function getTrackingWigetURL() {
$.ajax({
url: 'http://anotherdomain/getdetails',
dataType: 'jsonp',
jsonpCallback: 'MyJSONPCallback', 
success: function(data){
alert(data);
},error: function(response){
alert(response);
}
});
}
```

my controller code is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getdetails")
public @ResponseBody
String getdetails(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
return "test";
}
```

The server call is fine. but after executing it is always entering into the error block. The "data" alerted in the error block is not having my response data sent from controller. but when i inspect in firebug, i can able to see the response of the corresponding request is the response text sent from controller. i cant figure out where i missed or did wrong

Comment: That's not jsonp output. Could also send json if you CORS enable the output. http://enable-cors.org

Comment: That's not JSONP. Unless the receiving domain supports it, you will be blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: @Rory McCrossan can u give an idea how to make my server to respond such requests ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed related with the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), so security rules enforced in the browser.

Two ways to handle those cases:

- use JSONP ([Spring MVC supports this as of 4.1.0](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-jsonp))
- CORS ([Spring MVC will support this in the next version](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9278))

Note that you can achieve both with third party libraries or custom code before 4.1.0 - I'm merely pointing out official Spring support.

Comment: Don't forget that the receiving API needs to utilise both CORS and JSONP - you can't just change your code without support for them on the part of the 3rd party.